# Spring service unit testing using mockito

Tags: java, spring, junit, mockito

Until now answers from SO has been utterly satisfying for my problems. I'm learning unit testing with Junit and Mockito and I want to test my service class which is a part of my Spring web app. I read many tutorials and articles and I still have problems to write proper unit tests for my service layer. I would like to know answers for my questions, but first I paste some code:

**Service class**

```
public class AccountServiceImpl implements AccountService {

@Autowired
AccountDao accountDao, RoleDao roleDao, PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder, SaltSource saltSource;

@PersistenceContext
EntityManager entityManager;

public Boolean registerNewAccount(Account newAccount) {
    entityManager.persist(newAccount);
    newAccount.setPassword(passwordEncoder.encodePassword(newAccount.getPassword(), saltSource.getSalt(newAccount)));
    setRoleToAccount("ROLE_REGISTERED", newAccount);

    return checkIfUsernameExists(newAccount.getUsername());    
}

public void setRoleToAccount(String roleName, Account account) {
    List<Role> roles = new ArrayList<Role>();
    try {
        roles.add(roleDao.findRole(roleName));
    } catch(RoleNotFoundException rnf) {
        logger.error(rnf.getMessage());
    }
    account.setRoles(roles);
}

public Boolean checkIfUsernameExists(String username) {
    try {
        loadUserByUsername(username);
    } catch(UsernameNotFoundException unf) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {  
    try {
        Account loadedAccount = accountDao.findUsername(username);
        return loadedAccount;   
    } catch (UserNotFoundException e) {
        throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User: " + username + "not found!");
    }
}
}
```

**My unfinished test class**

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class AccountServiceImplTest {

private AccountServiceImpl accountServiceImpl;
@Mock private Account newAccount;
@Mock private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;
@Mock private SaltSource saltSource;
@Mock private EntityManager entityManager;
@Mock private AccountDao accountDao;
@Mock private RoleDao roleDao;

@Before
public void init() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    accountServiceImpl = new AccountServiceImpl();
    ReflectionTestUtils.setField(accountServiceImpl, "entityManager", entityManager);
    ReflectionTestUtils.setField(accountServiceImpl, "passwordEncoder", passwordEncoder);
    ReflectionTestUtils.setField(accountServiceImpl, "saltSource", saltSource);
    ReflectionTestUtils.setField(accountServiceImpl, "accountDao", accountDao);
    ReflectionTestUtils.setField(accountServiceImpl, "roleDao", roleDao);
}

@Test
public void testRegisterNewAccount() {
    Boolean isAccountCreatedSuccessfully = accountServiceImpl.registerNewAccount(newAccount);

    verify(entityManager).persist(newAccount);
    verify(newAccount).setPassword(passwordEncoder.encodePassword(newAccount.getPassword(), saltSource.getSalt(newAccount)));
    assertTrue(isAccountCreatedSuccessfully);
}

@Test
public void testShouldSetRoleToAccount() throws RoleNotFoundException{
    Role role = new Role(); //Maybe I can use mock here?
    role.setName("ROLE_REGISTERED");
    when(roleDao.findRole("ROLE_REGISTERED")).thenReturn(role);
    accountServiceImpl.setRoleToAccount("ROLE_REGISTERED", newAccount);
    assertTrue(newAccount.getRoles().contains(role)); 
}

}
```

**Questions**:

1. What is the best way to make unit tests where I have methods in methods like in my service class? Can I test them separately like above? [I divided my code into few methods to have cleaner code]
2. Is testRegisterNewAccount() good unit test for my service method? Test is green however I am not sure about it.
3. I am getting failure in my testShouldSetRoleToAccount. What am I doing wrong?
4. How to test checkIfUsernameExists?

Maybe someone will help me with this because I spent a couple of days and I didn't make a progress :(

---

**UPDATE**

**Finished test class**

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class AccountServiceImplTest extends BaseTest {

private AccountServiceImpl accountServiceImpl;
private Role role;
private Account account;
@Mock private Account newAccount;
@Mock private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;
@Mock private SaltSource saltSource;
@Mock private EntityManager entityManager;
@Mock private AccountDao accountDao;
@Mock private RoleDao roleDao;

@Before
public void init() {
    accountServiceImpl = new AccountServiceImpl();
    role = new Role();
    account = new Account();
    ReflectionTestUtils.setField(accountServiceImpl, "entityManager", entityManager);
    ReflectionTestUtils.setField(accountServiceImpl, "passwordEncoder", passwordEncoder);
    ReflectionTestUtils.setField(accountServiceImpl, "saltSource", saltSource);
    ReflectionTestUtils.setField(accountServiceImpl, "accountDao", accountDao);
    ReflectionTestUtils.setField(accountServiceImpl, "roleDao", roleDao);
}

@Test
public void testShouldRegisterNewAccount() {
    Boolean isAccountCreatedSuccessfully = accountServiceImpl.registerNewAccount(newAccount);

    verify(entityManager).persist(newAccount);
    verify(newAccount).setPassword(passwordEncoder.encodePassword(newAccount.getPassword(), saltSource.getSalt(newAccount)));
    assertTrue(isAccountCreatedSuccessfully);
}

@Test(expected = IllegalArgumentException.class)
public void testShouldNotRegisterNewAccount() {
    doThrow(new IllegalArgumentException()).when(entityManager).persist(account);
    accountServiceImpl.registerNewAccount(account);
}

@Test
public void testShouldSetRoleToAccount() throws RoleNotFoundException {
    when(roleDao.findRole(anyString())).thenReturn(role);
    accountServiceImpl.setRoleToAccount("ROLE_REGISTERED", account);
    assertTrue(account.getRoles().contains(role)); 
}

@Test
public void testShouldNotSetRoleToAccount() throws RoleNotFoundException {
    when(roleDao.findRole(anyString())).thenThrow(new RoleNotFoundException());
    accountServiceImpl.setRoleToAccount("ROLE_RANDOM", account);
    assertFalse(account.getRoles().contains(role));
}

@Test
public void testCheckIfUsernameExistsIsTrue() throws UserNotFoundException {
    when(accountDao.findUsername(anyString())).thenReturn(account);
    Boolean userExists = accountServiceImpl.checkIfUsernameExists(anyString());
    assertTrue(userExists);
}

@Test
public void testCheckIfUsernameExistsIsFalse() throws UserNotFoundException {
    when(accountDao.findUsername(anyString())).thenThrow(new UserNotFoundException());
    Boolean userExists = accountServiceImpl.checkIfUsernameExists(anyString());
    assertFalse(userExists);
}

@Test 
public void testShouldLoadUserByUsername() throws UserNotFoundException {
    when(accountDao.findUsername(anyString())).thenReturn(account);
    Account foundAccount = (Account) accountServiceImpl.loadUserByUsername(anyString());
    assertEquals(account, foundAccount);
}

@Test(expected = UsernameNotFoundException.class)
public void testShouldNotLoadUserByUsername() throws UserNotFoundException {
    when(accountDao.findUsername(anyString())).thenThrow(new UsernameNotFoundException(null));
    accountServiceImpl.loadUserByUsername(anyString());
}

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Question 1 - You've got a couple of options here.

Option 1 - write separate tests for each behaviour of each public method, based on what is required for that behaviour.  This keeps each test clean and separate, but it does mean that the logic in the secondary methods (such as `checkIfUsernameExists`) will be exercised twice.  In a sense, this is unnecessary duplication, but one advantage of this option is that if you change the implementation, but not the required behaviour, you'll still have good tests based on the behaviour.

Option 2 - use a Mockito Spy.  This is a little like a mock, except that you create it from a real object, and the default behaviour of it is that all the methods run as usual.  You can then stub out and verify the secondary methods, in order to test the methods that call them.

Question 2 - This looks like a good test for the "success" case of `registerNewAccount`.  Please think about what circumstances would cause `registerNewAccount` to fail and return false; and test this case.

Question 3 - I haven't had a good look at this; but try running with the debugger, and find out at which point your objects differ from what you expect.  If you can't work it out, post again and I'll have another look.

Question 4 - To test the negative case, stub your mock of the `AccountDao` to throw the required exception.  Otherwise, see my answers for question 1.

Comment: Thanks David. Reply to Question 1 i fully understand and i chose option 1. About Question 3 I managed to solve a problem. I had to replace mock Account with Account created by new operator and it was it [sic!] :). Question 4 also helped me, but I have other problems. As you can see thanks to your hints I managed to write tests for all my methods. They work ok except for testShouldNotSetRoleToAccount and testShouldNotLoadUserByUsername. The both fails when there is "expected = ...". Without it its ok. Moreover first also makes en error and test is <terminated> Error. Could you help me?

Comment: Sorry it's taken me a while to get back to you.  If those tests fail with the expected exception set, that means that the exception is not actually getting thrown.  Are you sure that `roleDao` and `accountDao` have actually been set to the mocks?  You could check this with the debugger.  Also, you're not using `anyString()` correctly - this is for stubbing and verifying, not actually running your method; I don't know whether this is the cause of your problem.  In the lines where you actually run your methods, put the actual value that you want to pass, instead of `anyString()`.

Comment: Eh lol, I am stupid. This error which I was talking about it was just console info from logger. In roleDao when exception is caught there is logger.error(..) :P. I looked at my test code thoroughly and now everything is ok. "expected" in testShouldNotSetRoleToAccount and testCheckIfUsernameExistsIsFalse is not needed. Later i will update my test class and we can close this discussion. Thanks once more David, your hints were very helpful :)